# Get Value of a Edit Text field

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am learning how to create UI elements. I have created a few EditText input fields. On the click of a Button I want to capture the content typed into that input field.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/name" android:width="220px" />
```

That's my field. How can I get the content?

Comment: The amout of upvotes somewhat proves that overriding `toString` does not yield the most discoverable API, however fancy is the technique.

Comment: The grammar and sentiment in your comment is really hard to understand...

Comment: @vemv The problem with the API is returning an `Editable` object where users expect and need a simple `String` 99% of times.

Comment: I think Android is cool, but I am surprised I had to Google for this (and for how to detect when the value has changed and is ready to read out, which can be complicated). I think they have made this harder than necessary!

Answer (score 737, accepted):

By using getText():

```
Button   mButton;
EditText mEdit;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Log.v("EditText", mEdit.getText().toString());
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: If you don't place EditText in the clas-wide scope, and instead declare it in OnCreate, it wants it to be declared as final. I assume it is better not to make it final, but is the only way to do so, to make it class-wide? IS making it class-wide the best way to go about this?

Comment: @PFranchise What do you mean by "class-wide"? Package protected (as in the example)? Private? Why wouldn't you want to have a widget accessible in the whole class?

Comment: <rant>Not a request for more information or suggestion. Also not a thanks or +1. THIS IS TERRIBLE! Why would anyone think this is the right way to design a text box. Also, EditText is the least intuitive name they could find. </rant>

Answer (score 26):

Get value from an `EditText` control in android. `EditText` `getText` property use to get value an `EditText`:

```
EditText txtname = findViewById(R.id.name);
String name      =  txtname.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 25):

I guess you will have to use this code when calling the "mEdit" your EditText object :

`myActivity.this.mEdit.getText().toString()`

Just make sure that the compiler know which `EditText` to call and use.

Comment: you should add explanation where does the "mEdit" come from.

Answer (score 11):

I hope this one should work:

```
Integer.valueOf(mEdit.getText().toString());
```

I tried `Integer.getInteger()` method instead of `valueOf()` - it didn't work.

Comment: This is assuming the value is an Integer... not sure where you picked that up in the question.

Answer (score 9):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

  Button  rtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
  EditText edit_text   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

    rtn .setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Log.v("EditText value=", edit_text.getText().toString());
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You might also want to take a look at [Butter Knife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/). It aims at reducing the amount of boilerplate code by using annotation. Here is a simple example:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @InjectView(R.id.name)
    EditText nameEditText;

    @InjectView(R.id.email)
    EditText emailEditText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);
        Butterknife.inject(this);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.submit)
    public void onSubmit() {
         Editable name = nameEditText.getText();
         Editable email = emailEditText.getText();
    }
}
```

Just add the following dependency to your `build.gradle`:

```groovy
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:x.y.z'
```

As an alternative there is also [AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org).

Answer (score 5):

### Shortest & Simplest

**`getText(editText);`**

**`getText(button);`**

**`getText(textView);`**

#### Little Workaround

Just make method in your BaseActivity / create BaseActivity if you don't have.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public String getText(TextView tv) {
        return tv.getText().toString().trim();
    } 
}
```

And extend your all activities by this BaseActivity.

```
public class YourActivity extends BaseActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     getText(editText);
     getText(button);
     getText(textView);
  }
}
```

Note that `EditText`, `Button` extends `TextView`, so I created only `getText(TextView tv)`.

Answer (score 4):

String value = YourEditText.getText().toString;

Answer (score 2):

A more advanced way would be to use butterknife bindview. This eliminates redundant code.

In your gradle under dependencies; add this 2 lines.

```
compile('com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-compat'
    }
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```

Then sync up.
Example binding edittext in MainActivity

```
import butterknife.BindView;   
import butterknife.ButterKnife; 

public class MainActivity {

@BindView(R.id.name) EditTextView mName; 
...

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         ButterKnife.bind(this); 
         ...
   }

}
```

But this is an alternative once you feel more comfortable or starting to work with lots of data.

Answer (score 2):

step 1 : create layout with name activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#c6cabd"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0e13"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv"
        android:hint="Input your country"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get EditText Text"
        android:layout_below="@id/et"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Step 2 : Create class Main.class

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String country = et.getText().toString();
                tv.setText("Your inputted country is : " + country);
            }
        });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kotlin and wants to make it generic you can use the Extension function

Extension function:

```
fun EditText.getTextString(): String {
    this.text.toString()
}
```

and call this method directly from your EditText

```
yourEditText.getTextString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.name); // your edittext id in xml
Button submit = findViewById(R.id.submit_button); // your button id in xml
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        String string = editText.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -9):

```
    Button kapatButon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.islemButonKapat);
    Button hesaplaButon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.islemButonHesapla);
    Button ayarlarButon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.islemButonAyarlar);

    final EditText ders1Vize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders1Vize);
    final EditText ders1Final = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders1Final);
    final EditText ders1Ortalama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders1Ortalama);

    //

    final EditText ders2Vize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders2Vize);
    final EditText ders2Final = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders2Final);
    final EditText ders2Ortalama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders2Ortalama);
    //
    final EditText ders3Vize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders3Vize);
    final EditText ders3Final = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders3Final);
    final EditText ders3Ortalama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders3Ortalama);
    //
    final EditText ders4Vize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders4Vize);
    final EditText ders4Final = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders4Final);
    final EditText ders4Ortalama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders4Ortalama);
    //
    final EditText ders5Vize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders5Vize);
    final EditText ders5Final = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders5Final);
    final EditText ders5Ortalama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders5Ortalama);
    //
    final EditText ders6Vize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders6Vize);
    final EditText ders6Final = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders6Final);
    final EditText ders6Ortalama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders6Ortalama);
    //
    final EditText ders7Vize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders7Vize);
    final EditText ders7Final = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders7Final);
    final EditText ders7Ortalama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ders7Ortalama);
    //

    /*
     * 
     * 
     * */

    kapatButon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // kapatma islemi
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "kapat",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    /*
     * 
     * 
     * */
    hesaplaButon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // hesap islemi

            int d1v = Integer.parseInt(ders1Vize.getText().toString());
            int d1f = Integer.parseInt(ders1Final.getText().toString());
            int ort1 = (int) (d1v * 0.4 + d1f * 0.6);
            ders1Ortalama.setText("" + ort1);
            //
            int d2v = Integer.parseInt(ders2Vize.getText().toString());
            int d2f = Integer.parseInt(ders2Final.getText().toString());
            int ort2 = (int) (d2v * 0.4 + d2f * 0.6);
            ders2Ortalama.setText("" + ort2);
            //
            int d3v = Integer.parseInt(ders3Vize.getText().toString());
            int d3f = Integer.parseInt(ders3Final.getText().toString());
            int ort3 = (int) (d3v * 0.4 + d3f * 0.6);
            ders3Ortalama.setText("" + ort3);
            //
            int d4v = Integer.parseInt(ders4Vize.getText().toString());
            int d4f = Integer.parseInt(ders4Final.getText().toString());
            int ort4 = (int) (d4v * 0.4 + d4f * 0.6);
            ders4Ortalama.setText("" + ort4);
            //
            int d5v = Integer.parseInt(ders5Vize.getText().toString());
            int d5f = Integer.parseInt(ders5Final.getText().toString());
            int ort5 = (int) (d5v * 0.4 + d5f * 0.6);
            ders5Ortalama.setText("" + ort5);
            //
            int d6v = Integer.parseInt(ders6Vize.getText().toString());
            int d6f = Integer.parseInt(ders6Final.getText().toString());
            int ort6 = (int) (d6v * 0.4 + d6f * 0.6);
            ders6Ortalama.setText("" + ort6);
            //
            int d7v = Integer.parseInt(ders7Vize.getText().toString());
            int d7f = Integer.parseInt(ders7Final.getText().toString());
            int ort7 = (int) (d7v * 0.4 + d7f * 0.6);
            ders7Ortalama.setText("" + ort7);
            //




            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hesapla",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```