# How can I read user input in Android?

Tags: java, android

I need to read a user input in android to process it later.

How can I do this?

In iPhone SDK I'd do something like this:

```
-(IBAction)command {
   system("echo %s", textfield.text");
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do by doing that ?

Comment: I'm trying to run a system command that requires user input which I need to take and use in the command

Comment: I want to get the text value of the text box

Comment: so, edit your question.... specify what you're asking, what was the expected result, what you have done so far (or have looked at what documentation), change the tag to "android" (and not source-code), change the title to "How can I read user input in android"...

Comment: sorry, is this a little better now?

Comment: perhaps take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531396/get-value-of-a-edit-text-field

Answer (score 1):

Put an `EditText` in your UI, and call `getText().toString()` on it when you need the value that the user typed in.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in you code:

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

And this is the textbox, or whatever:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And something like this to get the text of it:

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
          // Perform action on key press
          Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```