# Converting java program with Scanner into Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I created a java program that get input from the user by Scanner.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int first = scan.nextInt();
```

(I used more than 1 scanning).

Afterward I tried to create an Android application using my code, but the application got stack because the scanner.
How can I import the java scanner into Android studio?

Comment: Use `EditText` for getting user input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read user input in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849705/how-can-i-read-user-input-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Scanner is in Android.  See [Android Scanner JavaDoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Scanner).  Your program should work without conversion.

Maybe you need to add to your import statement(s) to `import java.util.*`. Just a guess.

It would help if you added the error message to your question.

Maybe the issue is not with `Scanner` but with `System.in`.   Try replacing `System.in` with a String constant Ex:`"This is my text"`;

Comment: Webre should I add the import statement?

Comment: There is no error message, the application just stop working.

Comment: Just write {     Scanner scan = new Scanner ("this is my text");       }?

Comment: Correct,  Just to see if it will work.   Then we will know if System.in is the problem.

Comment: I tried to run the program as method, and I got runtime error message when it tried to run the Scanner (the same one, I didn't change it) - Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:874)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1502)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2134)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2093)
        at