# Android getText from EditText field

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a problem with getting text from `EditText` field to insert it in Email composer with intent. I've declared `EditText` field in layout file (@+id/vnosEmaila):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/navodiloEmail"
    android:text="@string/navodiloEmail"
    android:textSize="15dip"/>
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/vnosEmaila"
    android:layout_below="@id/navodiloEmail"/>
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/navodiloZadeva"
    android:text="@string/navodiloZadeva"
    android:layout_below="@id/vnosEmaila"
    android:textSize="15dip"/>
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/vnosZadeve"
    android:layout_below="@id/navodiloZadeva"/>
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/navodiloBody"
    android:text="@string/navodiloBody"
    android:layout_below="@id/vnosZadeve"
    android:textSize="15dip"/>
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/vnosBody"
    android:layout_below="@id/navodiloBody"/>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/klicIntentEmail"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sestaviEmail"
    android:onClick="sestaviEmail"
    android:layout_below="@id/vnosBody"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The button calls onClick method "sestaviEmail" and I have declared it:

```
public void sestaviEmail (View view){
    CharSequence test = getText(R.id.vnosEmaila);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(EmailGumb.this, test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
    }
```

I'm just showing it with Toast because it's faster but everytime I try to get text from field I get "false". All other questions that I've found had code which declared Button in methods and not in layout, maybe this is a part of the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Value of a Edit Text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531396/get-value-of-a-edit-text-field)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Sample code for How to get text from `EditText`.

**Android Java Syntax**

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.vnosEmaila);
String value = text.getText().toString();
```

**Kotlin Syntax**

```
val text = findViewById<View>(R.id.vnosEmaila) as EditText
val value = text.text.toString()
```

Comment: There's always a warning that `text.getTExt()` could return null. got any good short and concise solution to check this? (that also looks like clean readable code?)

Comment: @DavidT I don't like the situation either, but I don't think there's anything unreadable about declaring `Editable editable = text.getText();` and then assigning your value like `value = editable == null ? "" : editable.toString();` (or whatever default/logic you want).

Answer (score 11):

Try this.

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
String  str = text.getText().toString().trim();
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this -

```
EditText myEditText =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vnosEmaila);

String text = myEditText.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this will solve ur problem ....

```
EditText etxt = (EditText)findviewbyid(R.id.etxt);
String str_value = etxt.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the text  in editText by applying below code:

```
EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.vnosZadeve);
String text=editText.getText().toString();
```

then you can toast string text!

Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
  setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

  //after setting yor layout do the following
  EditText email = (EdiText) findViewById(R.id.vnosEmaila);
  String val = email.getText().toString;   // Use the toString method to convert the return value to a String.

  //Your Toast with String val; 
  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(EmailGumb.this, val, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
  toast.show();
```

Thanks

Comment: You are missing .toString() call on your email.getText()!