# Set and load a certain text

Tags: android, text

I'm currently programming an app where you should enter a text which is stored. The text should be able to be loaded in the app (maybe another activity) then.

It should be able to be used this way:

```
task.execute(new String[]{city,lang});
```

Is this makeable?

Thanks

Comment: how do you want to store your text?, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: The text should be a code string, is that possible? As city and lang are strings but they are hardcoded strings currently

Comment: Assuming you don't want to store the data persistently and just want to use it directly, you can follow [the official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html), especially "Build an Intent" and "Receive the Intent".

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Edittext` on your first `Activity` on which user can type something.You can get that "something" programmatically in the same activity as a string.Now if you want to avail that string to another activity then you can use an `Intent` from the first activity to the second activity which will avail that string in the second activity.

Comment: How can I get it as a string?

Comment: [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200108/android-gettext-from-edittext-field) to know how to get an `EditText` value as a string.

Comment: @user3272495 : Did it solve your problem? If it helped you solving your issue please accept this as an answer.