# Android App crashes when pressing a Button in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, crash

I switched from Java to Kotlin and I am completely new.
I tried to make an app that calculates your age to minute.
The `age` input is through `EditText` in Android Studio.
Then to set your age into `TextView`.

When I press on the button that application crashes.
Below is the Kotlin Code

```kotlin
        var edtTxtAge = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edtTxtAge)
        val btnCalc = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnCalc)
        var txtAge = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtAge)

        btnCalc.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

            val minutesPerYear = 525600
            val age = edtTxtAge.toString().toInt() * minutesPerYear
            txtAge.text = "Your age in minutes is: " + age.toString()

        })
```

Comment: `val age = edtTxtAge.text.toString().toInt() * minutesPerYear`

Comment: See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200108/android-gettext-from-edittext-field

Comment: show error code please.

Comment: Please provide the stack trace of the crash.

Comment: This is the error log: NumberFormatException: For input string:

Comment: yeah. i assume that. Make sure your edittext value is `int`.

Comment: Thanks @IntelliJAmiya
Answer is:`val age = edtTxtAge.text.toString().toInt() * minutesPerYear`
            `txtAge.text = "Your age in minutes is: " + age.toString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When initialising age you must call "text" before you call to string:

```
var edtTxtAge = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edtTxtAge)
    val btnCalc = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnCalc)
    var txtAge = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtAge)

    btnCalc.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

        val minutesPerYear = 525600
        val age = edtTxtAge.text.toString().toInt() * minutesPerYear
        txtAge.text = "Your age in minutes is: " + age.toString()

    })
```