# getting data from dynamically created table row containing many textviews

Tags: android

i created a table row dynamically, That contains three textviews.now i want to get the value of three textview's value on click on tablerow(tr).means i want to get the companyTV,valueTV & YearTV's value.
Thanks.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tv_bg));
        tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));


        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        companyTV = new TextView(this);
        companyTV.setText(match[i]);
        companyTV.isClickable();
        companyTV.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        companyTV.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        companyTV.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        companyTV.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tr.addView(companyTV);  // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating another textview **/
        valueTV = new TextView(this);
        valueTV.setText(kanr[i]);
        valueTV.isClickable();
        valueTV.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        valueTV.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        valueTV.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        valueTV.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        tr.addView(valueTV); // Adding textView to tablerow.


        YearTV = new TextView(this);
        YearTV.setText(ort[i]);

        YearTV.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        YearTV.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        YearTV.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        YearTV.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        tr.addView(YearTV); // Adding textView to tablerow.


        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have one error in your code when you are setting background of table row before you have created it. You should first create new table row, and then set its background:

```
for (int i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
    /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
    tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tv_bg));
```

You can access table row children views by index in your `OnClickListener`

```
        tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                TableRow tr = (TableRow)v;
                TextView companyTV, valueTV, yearTV;
                String company, value, year;
                companyTV = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(0);
                valueTV = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(1);
                yearTV = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(2);
                company = companyTV.getText().toString();
                value = valueTV.getText().toString();
                year = yearTV.getText().toString();
            }
        });
```

If you want to track which table row is currently selected, you can create global variable for your activity

```
TableRow selectedTR;
```

and then set that inside `OnClickListener`

```
selectedTR = (TableRow)v;
```

When you use that `selectedTR` variable make sure that you check it for null value in case there is no selection made yet.

Comment: one more question please. if i want to make table-row selectable and after selecting the tr i will click on button to get the data. i got the data. now i just wanted to make it selectable. and how to identify which tr is selected? Again Thank you so much.

Comment: Yeahh.. and its done!! thank you so much. you just saved my job.

Comment: If you please dont mind.. would you like to have a look on my another problem. that is..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644863/multilingual-android-app-using-spinner

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713771/taking-string-after-a-particularword-in-android/28714451#28714451

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851744/android-listview-setonitemclicklistner-not-working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317434/list-view-changes-position-of-imageview-on-scroll       please see this.. :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132225/sending-multiple-data-to-server-in-predefined-format

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164887/how-to-implode-files-in-java please have a look on this