# ListView setOnItemClickListner not working

Tags: android

I am using listview since long but this time i am facing a weird problem. that is i want to put setonitemclick listner on it but its not working i could not figure it out where is the issue. i have another xml for listview that shows the datas.

xml:

```
 <ListView android:id="@+id/lv" 
android:dividerHeight="5dp" 
android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
android:clickable="true" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
```

code:

```
package algonation.com.noteup;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

   private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private DBManager dbManager;

    private ListView listView;

    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    final String[] from = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.TAG_TITLE,
            DatabaseHelper.TAG_TIME,DatabaseHelper._ID,
            DatabaseHelper.ADD_TAG
             };



    final int[] to = new int[] {R.id.title,  R.id.time,R.id.textView4,R.id.fullnote};
    private View f;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        dbManager = new DBManager(this);
        dbManager.open();
        final Animation animAlpha = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alfa);
        final Button btnmain =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        final Button btn_addnote = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final Button btn_TakePic =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        btn_addnote.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btn_TakePic.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnmain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                v.startAnimation(animAlpha);
                Intent  i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Camera.class);
                startActivity(i);
                btn_addnote.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btn_TakePic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                btnmain.setText("X");
            }
        });
        Cursor cursor = dbManager.fetch();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_view_record, cursor, from, to, 0);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);

       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "fdfdfd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });

            mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

       }
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
             case R.id.add:

                Intent add_tag =  new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddNote.class);
                startActivity(add_tag);

                return true;
            }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

         public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add xml code also fr listview

Comment: listview1.setFocusable(false); and also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208285/listview-itemclick-not-work

Comment: @Pragna it does not letting put the code. but literally it have for textviews like title,full not and so. and <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"> this is in main acitivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well finally i got solution by doing R&D. the solution is just adding a line to root of the list element layout. 
`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`
this's working pretty fine in my case. 
bytheway thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.bringToFront();
```

try this before

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener();
```

Comment: is ur listview scrolling ??

Comment: Ok then listView.bringToFront(); not the solution.

Comment: than what is the the issue?

Comment: i updated the main xml and the another xml for listview containes four textviews.

Comment: i cant see your main.xml

Comment: <ListView android:id="@+id/lv" 
android:dividerHeight="5dp" 
android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
android:clickable="true" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

Comment: i want whole main.xml not this.

Comment: will you please tell me your mail i will send whole code. here it does not letting me upload whole code. than you can post answer here for the sake of others.

Comment: i sent the whole project.

Comment: if i retrieves image from sqlite setOnItemClickListener works but without image it doesnt works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138883/getting-values-from-sqlite-using-group-by-null-pointer