# Listview Click doesn't fire

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a listview, whick get its data from a SQLite db. I would like to let user change value of field by click on items. But with following code, the click event is not fired. Could some one help on it? Thanks!

```
public class BDXDeviceActivity extends Activity {

    private DeviceListControl deviceListControl;
    private ListView listViewDevice;
    private DeviceListAdapter2 deviceListAdapter2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // using a custom layout, otherwise a system default of List
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_list);
        listViewDevice = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDevice);

        deviceListControl = new DeviceListControl(this);

        // setListAdapter(new DeviceListAdapter2(this, deviceListControl.getDevices()));
        deviceListAdapter2 = new DeviceListAdapter2(this, deviceListControl.getDevices());
        listViewDevice.setAdapter(deviceListAdapter2);

        listViewDevice.setClickable(true);
        listViewDevice.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
    }

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            DeviceName deviceName = (DeviceName) listViewDevice.getAdapter().getItem(position);

            deviceListControl.deleteDevice(deviceName.getId());

            // after delete, reread the list adapter and get names list via namechange
            deviceListAdapter2 = new DeviceListAdapter2(getBaseContext(), deviceListControl.getDevices());
            listViewDevice.setAdapter(deviceListAdapter2);

            // Display success information
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
```

... layout file

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtSearchDevice"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#f7f5b1a3"
        android:focusable="false"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchDevice"
        android:textColor="#ff151515"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:focusable="false"/>

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewDevice"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

    </ListView>
```

Comment: Able to see toast message ?

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K, no toast message. I added layout file in my question

Comment: try `listview.bringToFront();`

Comment: @DevendraSingh thanks, but it doesn't work.

Comment: did you inflated another view for list?

Comment: [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851744/listview-setonitemclicklistner-not-working/29004435#29004435)

Comment: @DevendraSingh I have only one view. Thanks, I will try the method of the link and report back, thanks!

Comment: Find the problem. In the row layout xml file, one Edittext is still android:focusable = "true". After deleting it. the click event works. Thanks all!