# List View changes position of ImageView On scroll

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using List View with custom array adapter the adapter sets data from Sqlite. But when the list items reach over 10 (or list becomes scroll able) the Image View changes position automatically if i scrolls continue. here is my custom adapter's code.Thanks

```
public class CustomeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
 public Context context;

 public ArrayList<String> titleArrayList, descArrayList, timeArrayList, imgArrayList, IdArrayList;
    List data;
    int layoutResID;
    private Bitmap myBitmap;

    public CustomeAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<String> titleArrayList, ArrayList<String> descArrayList, ArrayList<String> timeArrayList, ArrayList<String> imgArrayList, ArrayList<String> IdArrayList) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, titleArrayList);
        this.context = context;
        this.titleArrayList = titleArrayList;
        this.descArrayList = descArrayList;
        this.timeArrayList = timeArrayList;
        this.imgArrayList = imgArrayList;
        this.IdArrayList = IdArrayList;
        this.data = data;
        this.layoutResID = layoutResourceId;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        final StockQuoteView sqView;

        if (rowView == null) {


            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
            sqView = new StockQuoteView();
            sqView.tag = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_fullnote);

            sqView.desc = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            sqView.time = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
            sqView.id = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            sqView.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

            sqView.button1 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button1);
            sqView.button2 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button2);
            sqView.button3 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button3);
            sqView.button4 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button4);
            rowView.setTag(sqView);
        } else {
            sqView = (StockQuoteView) rowView.getTag();
        }

        try {
            sqView.tag.setText(titleArrayList.get(position));
            sqView.desc.setText(descArrayList.get(position));
            sqView.time.setText(timeArrayList.get(position));
            sqView.id.setText(IdArrayList.get(position));
            sqView.id.setTag(IdArrayList.get(position).toString());
            if (imgArrayList.get(position).contains("null")) {
                sqView.img.setImageBitmap(null);
                sqView.img.setTag("null");
            } else {
                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgArrayList.get(position));
                //sqView.img.setImageBitmap((position & 1) == 1 ? myBitmap : myBitmap);
                String TAG = "tag";
                String id = String.valueOf(position);

                sqView.img.setTag(imgArrayList.get(position).toString());
                int width = myBitmap.getWidth();
                int height = myBitmap.getHeight();
                int newWidth = (height > width) ? width : height;
                int newHeight = (height > width) ? height - (height - width) : height;
                int crop = (width - height) / 2;
                crop = (crop < 0) ? 0 : crop;
                Bitmap cropImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap, crop, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                sqView.img.setImageBitmap(cropImg);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e.toString());
        }


        return rowView;
    }

    protected static class StockQuoteView {
        protected TextView tag;
        protected TextView desc;
        protected TextView time;
        protected ImageView img;
        protected ImageView button1;
        protected ImageView button2;
        protected ImageView button3;
        protected ImageView button4;
        public TextView id;
    }


}
`
```

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but you can make your getView() more readable by passing convertView into your ViewHolder and doing all your findViewById() calls in there.  An example: https://github.com/androidfu/Now-Playing/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/androidfu/nowplaying/app/ui/adapters/MovieAdapter.java note, however, that I'm using ButterKnife but the principal is the same.  You can also ditch rowView and just use convertView.  rowView isn't hurting anything, but it makes it harder to read.  I am glad to see a SO question that has a ViewHolder implemented for once though.

Comment: i tried a trick e.g. because in my case these is possibility of a null image so i just hide the imageviews that containing null value and made visible to others that are having images path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this line`sqView.img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` after `sqView.img.setTag("null");` and Make Visible back the imageView in the else statment like `else {sqView.img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgArrayList.get(position));
                //sqView.img.setImageBitmap((position & 1) == 1 ? myBitmap : myBitmap);
                String TAG = "tag";
                String id = String.valueOf(position);............}`
this is tricked only.