# Getting "infinity" value from textfield on android

Tags: android, android-fragments, textfield, calculator, infinity

im making a simple bodyfat calculator inside a fragment, im getting infinity value when running the app, then i tried to see if it was getting a 0 vale from the variable bodyweight and indeed, is getting a 0 value, im new on fragments, maybe something is wrong with it?

here is the code

```
public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText etBodyWeight, etWaist;
    Button btnCalculate;
    TextView tvResult;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);

        etBodyWeight=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tfBodyWeight);
        etWaist=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tfWaist);
        tvResult=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
        btnCalculate=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);

        btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            int bodyweight, waist;
            Double  factor1, factor2, lbm, bfw, bfp;
            String result;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try{
                bodyweight=Integer.parseInt(etBodyWeight.toString());
                }

                catch(NumberFormatException e){

                    System.out.println("numero no valido");

                }


                factor1=(bodyweight*1.082)+94.42;

                try{
                waist=Integer.parseInt(etWaist.toString());
                }

                catch(NumberFormatException e){

                    System.out.println("numero no valido");
                }


                factor2=waist*4.15;



                lbm=factor1-factor2;
                bfw=bodyweight-lbm;
                bfp=(bfw*100)/bodyweight;
               result=Double.toString(bfp);

               tvResult.setText(result);




            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
Integer.parseInt(etBodyWeight.getText().toString());
```

instead of:

```
Integer.parseInt(etBodyWeight.toString());
```

Also see the answer [here for getting value from EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4531396/3879470).
Also change to     `etWaist.getText().toString()`.

Comment: ooh, thanks, that solve the issue hehe, i feel dumb now, thanks mane, yeah, long time i didnt use android, i forgot that, thanks.

Comment: @GregorioMerazJr. also, if a `NumberFormatException` occurs the result will be meaningless, so you should display an error message and not continue with the computation

Comment: oh, thanks, you mean to display a toast when the error ocurrs?