# Display users input from editText field on a textView

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, gettext

I use `getText();` on an `editText` using the code below and want the users input to replace a `textView` then how do I do this?
 btw the code was taken from this question:
[Get Value of a Edit Text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531396/get-value-of-a-edit-text-field)

```
Button   mButton;
EditText mEdit;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);

mButton.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Log.v("EditText", mEdit.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little better what your specific problem is? I don't see an attempt here from what I understand of the question

Comment: do you want to set EditText empty after user click too ?

Comment: Specifically I want one edit text box at the bottom of the page and 6 textViews at the top of the page with variables holding the spots.  one textView on top of the editText field at the bottom of page will have 6 questions that show one at a time.  So the user will answer the first question and that will replace the variable in one of the textViews and then a second question will appear in the textView above the editText box ....  I apologize for my lack of clarity as I am very new to programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Find your textView

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
```

2- After you get the text from EditText set it to TextView :

```
txt.setText(mEdit.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an array of TextView would be nice in your case.

```
TextView [] myTexts = new TextView[6];
myTexts[0]=findViewById(R.id.txt1);
myTexts[1]=findViewById(R.id.txt2);
...
myTexts[5]=findViewById(R.id.txt6);

int questionNumber = 0;
mButton.setOnClickListener(
new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        myTexts[questionNumber].setText(mEdit.getText().toString());
        questionNumber++;
     }
});
```

questionNumber integer will hold the value of which question is going to be answered but don't let its value to be greater then 5 if you don't want ArrayIndexOutOfRange exception.

Comment: What problems? Can you elaborate !

Comment: I have elaborated with your code implemented here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270532/using-textview-arrays-for-questionnaire-app

Answer (score -1):

```
Button   mButton;
EditText mEdit;
TextView mText;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

mButton.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Log.v("EditText", mEdit.getText().toString());
            mText.setText(mEdit.getText.toString());
        }
    });
}
```