# How do I get an EditText input into a variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im new to this so sorry if the answer is really obvious...

so I have an EditText were the user inputs their name:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_above="@+id/analogClock"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
        android:hint="Enter Your Name"/>
```

When they fill in the name, i would like to take their name and put it into a variable but im really unsure,

Thanks in advance

Comment: google or stackoverflow is your friend :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531396/get-value-of-a-edit-text-field

Comment: Sorry but what variable in the code is the peice of info stored in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String text= et.getEditableText().toString();
}
```

Comment: oh okay thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText).getText().toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 EditText eText; 

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
      eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
      String str = eText.getText().toString();  
  } 
  }
```

I understand you want it? Is that so?