# How to display the EditText fields text in the TextView

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio, android-developer-api

Of late I was just trying to create a mems geneator app, yes I had been following the new bostons and in that buckey created them using 2 fragments and here i just want to do in a single main activity, but I just can't figure out how to retrieve the text from the edit text field and set the text of Text view to it. I know it's pretty a newbie question but still I don't know how to code it so please help...

I had just imported some widgets,views,etc and done some modified the on create function and my on create function is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static EditText topText;
public static EditText bottomtext;
public static TextView top;
public static TextView bottom;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    topText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.topedit);
    bottomtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bottomedit);
    top = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.top);
    bottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bottom);
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View V) {
                    top.setText((CharSequence) topText);
                    bottom.setText((CharSequence) bottomtext);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
if(topText.getText()!=null){
top.setText(topText.getText().toString());
}
if(bottomtext.getText()!=null){
bottom.setText(bottomtext.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: Also read full documentation of android before coming to the implementations, you will find almost everything in the documentation. You can refer to http://developer.android.com

Comment: Thanks man it worked with just some small modification i.e inverting null and the topText.getText() and the same for bottom also like-  if(null != topText.getText()){
                            top.setText(topText.getText().toString());
                        }
                        if (null != bottomtext.getText()) {
                            bottom.setText(bottomtext.getText().toString());
                        }

Comment: glad to help, please mark as correct if my answer was helpful

Comment: inverted  like what? are you asking about changing topText.getText()!=null to null != topText.getText() ??

Comment: yes bro but just leave it,bcz at first it asked to invere it like i mention above but now it worked fine with out inverting also any way thanks for your help...!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get text of the EditText field:

```
CharSequence text = topText.getText();
```

And set the text above for the textView:

```
top.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this short example to understand the concept

store=ret.getText().toString();

show.setText(store);

**Explanation**

ret: is the name of the edit text field;

store: is used to hold anything gotten from ret (text field)

show.setText(store) displays the result in the textview

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered:

"Use getText() on your EditText object".

[Get Value of a Edit Text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531396/get-value-of-a-edit-text-field)

Next time do a quick search ;)