# Edit Text getText().toString() returns blank

Tags: android

I am doing a simple login app where i need to pass the user id to subsequent screens. But,i am not getting the username field to a variable.

```
 public static String user;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPwd);
    Button blogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLogin);


    user = username.getText().toString();// Here user variable is blank!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Kindly help!!!

Comment: It will always blank in onCreate() method, you need to write it in on button click event, then only you can get value

Comment: okay .for test case add `username.setText("I am sourav");`  before  `user`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Value of a Edit Text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531396/get-value-of-a-edit-text-field)

Comment: If you are setting static value in xml for that edittext, only then you can get that value in onCreate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user = username.getText().toString();
```

put this line into a listener like a button click

Comment: Thanks. But why does a simple text field needs to be registered under an event.

Comment: You need to understand the activity lifecycle, Your activity is created the moment your app is started.  you input the text at later stage when your activity has already started, So you need a interface to listen for the change in the state of your edittext, hence you need to add it in a button click listener, i hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

that code should be written inside `onClickListener` of blogin `Button`

```
blogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            user = username.getText().toString();

        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must get the user field when blogin is clicked:

```
blogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
   {
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
          user = username.getText().toString();
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code on onCreate

```
public static String user;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPwd);
    Button blogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLogin);


 // On the click of the button get username string.
    blogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              user = username.getText().toString();  
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

you get text of username field immediately. and I guess not text has been set in the filed before. when a editText has no text, it's return `""`. you must create `onClickListener` event for your `blogin` button and use getText of `username` textView after user entered its username and then click on the button

```
public static String user;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPwd);
    Button blogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLogin);

    blogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          if(username.getText().toString().equals(""){
              Toast.makeText(v.getContext, "enter your username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
          else
              user = username.getText().toString();  
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are evaluating value of editText on onCreate(); that will return empty always so just evaluate the editText when you need it.
as you want it on button clickListner();

```
        blogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                user = username.getText().toString();

            }
        });
```