# reverse search by image with keyword

Tags: java, android

I developed an app that can reverse search by image. I wish user can use image and keyword at the same time to reverse search.

The method `getImgurContent()` works. It returns image's URL on the internet. But I don't know how to reverse search image with keyword at the same time.

```
uri = Uri.parse("https://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=" + getImgurContent());
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531396/get-value-of-a-edit-text-field

Comment: I know how to get text. Thank you. But My question is how to "reverse search by image" with keyword.I'm so sorry what I wrote caused your misunderstanding.

Comment: You already are searching by an image, no? Except it's only Imgur images? "Image by keyword" doesn't make sense to me, because that's two separate things. 1) Find images by a keyword, e.g. find images from getting text 2) Reverse search on a particular one

Comment: Because Google's reverse image search doesn't work well everytime. Like sometime you use leaves image to reverse search but the result is all flower just because the leaves are too colorful. I wish my app can accurately show the result that user actually want. User can key in the keyword before Google search guessing what kind of the thing's image is.Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Google themselves use Tensorflow for image detection, as far as I know. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition

Answer (score 0):

You can try code below:

```
uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=findSomeImage");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Or:

```
uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q="+ getImgurContent());
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I want to "reverse" search image. Not just search image by keyword. And the second code can't work. The method `getImgurContent()` is return image's URL on the internet not keyword.But thank you for your answer ^^.