# Comparing EditText with EditText values

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code, I'm trying to compare the input in my edit text field to ensure their equal value before it creates an account.

```
     //compare the fields contents
    if(editTextPassword.equals(editTextReEnterPassword)) {
        //they are equal
        //Creating a new user
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class));
                        } else{
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Could not register... please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }else {//they are not equal
        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Passwords do not match... please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Are `editTextPassword` and  `editTextReEnterPassword` the names of your editText?

Comment: @Einzig7 Yup you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the text value of the edit text.

So, really, you can not do `editText.equals()`

You would do something like this..

```
String editTextPasswordString = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
String editTextReEnterPasswordString = editTextReEnterPassword.getText().toString().trim();

if(editTextPasswordString.equals(editTextReEnterPasswordString)) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for offering your help but when I tried your solution, and run the app it's fine until I create a new account now then the app crash.

Comment: can you please post the crash log in your original post? thats the only way we can help.

Comment: No worries I added .trim to String editTextPasswordString = editTextPassword.getText().toString(); and it worked!

Comment: .trim() removes the empty space at the end. @CalebLee

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the value from EditText using the method *getText().toString()*, like this:

`String newPassword= editTextReEnterPassword.getText().toString();`

For more information about the method, please check the follow link:
[Get Value of EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531396/get-value-of-a-edit-text-field)

After that, you need to compare the previous string **editTextPassword** with the new one created, which is the result of the method *getText()*, **editTextReEnterPassword**.

So your final code, should be like this:

```
String newPassword = editTextReEnterPassword.getText().toString();
String atualPassword = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

if(atualPassword.equals(newPassword))
{
    ...
}
else 
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(editTextPassword.getText().toString().equals(editTextReEnterPassword.getText().toString()))
```

`EditText` is not a `String`

Comment: Thanks for offering your help but when I tried your solution, and run the app it's fine until I create a new account now then the app crash.

Comment: This is a different problem. Edit your code with the necessary changes that the answers provided for the EditText comparison problem and present a new question for your current problem.