# How to get a text from Edittext into a Toast?

Tags: java, android, toast

My task is to get input text in EditText into a toast when I press the button and if there is no text, do nothing, but app crashes whenever I try to open it. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);

    public void cLickFuntion(View view){
        String nameString=name.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),nameString,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Value of a Edit Text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531396/get-value-of-a-edit-text-field)

Comment: I'm guessing `EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);` this line is causing the crash because you're calling it before the view has been created.

Comment: @Quinn That's true, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Declare EditText as global and change onCreate like below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);

    }

    public void cLickFuntion(View view){
        String nameString=name.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),nameString,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!