# Naming Buttons through User Input

Tags: java, android

So I´m having three Buttons which lead to other Activities with a normal Click. Now i want to name the buttons through a longer Click and User Input. So short click goes forward, long Click ability to rename it. So far i was able to rename the button with a long click, but only to a predetermined String. My code so far.

```
public class MainActivity<button1> extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        button = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> opensecondone());
        button.setOnLongClickListener(v -> naming());


        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button55);
        button1.setOnClickListener(a -> opensecondsecond());
        button1.setOnLongClickListener(v -> naming1());

        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button40);
        button2.setOnClickListener(a -> opensecondthird());
        button2.setOnLongClickListener(v -> naming2());
    }

    public boolean naming() {
        button = this.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button.setText("message");
        return true;
    }
    public boolean naming1() {
        button = this.findViewById(R.id.button55);
        button.setText("Your Text");
        return true;
    }
    public boolean naming2() {
        button = this.findViewById(R.id.button40);
        button.setText("Your Text");
        return true;
    }
    
    public void opensecondone() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, firmaeins.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void opensecondsecond() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, firmaZwei.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void opensecondthird() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, firmaDrei.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, what is your question ?

Comment: Does that mean you cant change your Button name with the text you got from the EditText ?

Comment: add a edit text set visibility to gone when long press set visibility of edittext to visible and ask user to name that button so obviously he will type something get that text and set it to your button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting text user input can be accomplished by using the [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText) class which can hold user input.

Once you have setup your EditText, you can use the user input in your naming function using [getText()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531396/get-value-of-a-edit-text-field).

1. Define an EditText.

```java
EditText editText1
```

2. Find the reference for the EditText.

```java
editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

3. The user input is now available from the EditText object.

```java
public boolean naming() {
    button = this.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button.setText(editText1.getText().toString());
    return true;
}
```