# why my android studio app crash when i send data to my firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

hi my android studio app keeps crashing when im sending data to firebase, the logcat gives me this error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Found conflicting getters for name getText on class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.(CustomClassMapper.java:629)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(CustomClassMapper.java:377)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:177)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:140)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:104)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(CustomClassMapper.java:78)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.convertAndParseDocumentData(UserDataReader.java:231)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.parseSetData(UserDataReader.java:75)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(DocumentReference.java:167)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(DocumentReference.java:147)
at com.example.finalproject3.RegisterScreen$1$1.onComplete(RegisterScreen.java:82)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
2021

Comment: https://github.com/orelvak/finalproject.git this is my code over here id appriciate if someone can tell me what i do wrong,thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you're trying to send an `EditText` control to the database. Since Firebase only supports JSON types and an `EditText` is not a JSON type, you get an error message that says that.

You probably want to send the value that the user entered into the `EditText` to the database, so have a look at: [Get Value of a Edit Text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531396/get-value-of-a-edit-text-field)

Comment: actually i tried whats over that post right now, now it wont give me errors anymore but my app keeps on crashing when i try to submit the data

Comment: https://github.com/orelvak/finalproject.git thats my code when i run it no errors, build is good but when i send data its crashing,what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not going to check your entire project on another site for other errors, that's simply not how Stack Overflow works. Instead I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and editing your question to include such a repro.